# "Method Not Found" Error while using Get-PnPSiteTemplate

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to extract a site template of our site(*based on the Communication site template*) and restore it onto a new one.  Whenever I run the below command, I am seeing an error as below

```
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "C:\bin\ONNProd.xml" -Handlers PageContents,Lists,Pages,Theme,Fields -IncludeAllPages

Get-PnPSiteTemplate : Method not found: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1<Boolean> Enumerator.MoveNextAsync()'.
```

Checking the version of PnP.Powershell using
`Get-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell` gives me as 1.7.0

Can some one help me what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSCode, this could be a bug with the Powershell extension as laid out here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120026

I had the same issue, but when running the code from Powershell ISE, it is running now

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a bug with the most recent version (v1.7 and possible v1.6) of `PNP.PowerShell` for this function.  I was able to successfully get this to run by installing the 1.5 version.

Run this to install:

```
Install-Module PNP.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 1.5.0 -AllowClobber
```